# Windows Firewall: How to allow traffic on a specific port (eg. 8080)?

Tags: windows-7, port-forwarding, iis-6, windows-firewall

I am trying to configure team Foundation Server so that:

1. It is accessible from within my Home Network, and
2. The Web site is accessible via the Internet

I have a problem with point 1:

When I access `http://192.168.1.106:8080/tfs/web/` locally from 192.168.1.106, it works.

When I access the same web site from another PC in my home network, the above URL works only if I turn off the Firewall on `192.168.1.106`.

Can someone please tell me specifically how to allow traffic on port 8080 without turning off Windows Firewall? It seems that the exceptions that I specify are intended for listing programs on the box that need to communicate out. Is IIS the program that I need to make the exception for?     How do I specify that port 8080 traffic should be allowed for web site traffic on this port?

I hope to have success with point #2 later but I figure #1 should be done first. I expect issues.

Answer (score 28):

Create a new inbound rule with Windows Firewall with Advanced Security. The type in this case would be port, then on the next page you enter 8080 as the port. On the next page select either "Allow the connection", or "Allow the connection if it is secure". Select when the rule applies, and finally give the rule a name.