# Which Port And Protocol Is Being Blocked

Tags: windows-7, firewall, port, windows-firewall, protocol

I wrote a .NET program to make an HTTP request over the Internet, and it's being blocked by my PC's firewall.  The operating system being used is Windows 7.  I figured I could create an outbound rule to allow connections on port 80 using TCP to be made.  I also made the same rule for Inbound connections.  Unfortunately, the program still throws an error.  When I allow all outbound connections to be made, my program does not throw any errors.  Is there some firewall rule which is not program specific that I can add which will allow the type of connection being made by my program?  I was thinking of a firewall rule for a specific port and protocol, but I don't know how to configure such a rule...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Firewall: How to allow traffic on a specific port (eg. 8080)?](http://superuser.com/questions/144482/windows-firewall-how-to-allow-traffic-on-port-8080)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was just using the wrong port.  I was specifying port 80, since my program is requesting information via HTTP.  However, the port number being used seems to be somewhere between 10,000 and 60,000 (haven't narrowed it down yet).  I should probably start using some tool to monitor network traffic on my PC...

Answer (score 1):

When you edit the firewall rule, make sure you go to the "advanced options" tab and select all scopes "private + public + domain". This one can be sometimes skipped.

From your post I see you only need an "outgoing" firewall rule. Review if you have any deny/blocking rules that can affect you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, these are great things to check that I didn't consider.  Turns out I was just specifying the wrong port number...