# Windows 2003: how to permit traffic on ports 80 & 443 via Windows Firewall?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, windows-server-2003

These questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/144482/windows-firewall-how-to-allow-traffic-on-a-specific-port-eg-8080) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/402693/windows-firewall-block-everything-except-one-app-on-port-80) address the same issue but for Windows 7.

Unfortunately, we're stuck on Windows 2003.

Yes, we want to migrate but we have a custom, arcane piece of software tied to Windows 2003 and lack other options at this juncture. Please no suggestions about moving; we know it's a problem and are exploring alternatives.

On Windows 2003, how can you exclude all network traffic, except web traffic, i.e., packets via ports 80 & 443?. There doesn't appear to be a way to configure firewall rules.

Comment: idk Win03 at all, so just generically... It's the same general principle as your links - rules are cumulative, so 'allow 80', allow 443', 'deny all'

Comment: IIRC you do this through group policy. Be warned: Unless you have physical access to the server's console, you'll need to open more than just ports 80 & 443.

Comment: @Twisty great point will need access to RDP port, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Tetsujin yes but where do you specify the rules?

Comment: @Twisty any other ports you suggest leaving open? RDP, HTTP, HTTPS ... anything else?

Comment: If you manage your server via RDP, then port 3389/tcp is all that's necessary.  Test first and have a backup plan in case you accidentally lock yourself out.

Comment: To get into the firewall run `firewall.cpl`.  You need to start the Internet Connection Sharing service if it's not already running.

Comment: @Twisty thanks! would you like to post as an answer so you can get credit?

Answer (score 1):

The firewall in Windows 2003 will work the same as it does in XP. If you aren't seeing the control panel (run `firewall.cpl`) then you might not have it installed. It was not included in RTM flat, you must install the latest service pack. The firewall was introduced in Win2003 SP1 but you really need to be on SP2 for a wide variety of reasons.

1. Install SP2
2. Run Windows update
3. run `firewall.cpl`

What version are you running? (The final build is 3790)

SOURCE:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003#Service_Pack_1

Comment: Running Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If @Twisty doesn't want credit, you'll get credit for answering the question. Thanks again!

Comment: It's OK. Let @HackSlash have the credit. Thanks!